# There was an error saving the channel: Namespace not found (Cortana channel)

Tags: botframework, cortana, cortana-skills-kit

We just created a botframework account and created a new bot using the basic template. The both is deployed in Azure.

When we try to add the Cortana channel, we get the following error when saving the channel configuration:

> Oops. We had trouble saving your configuration
>
> There was an error saving the channel:
>
> Namespace not found

Another error that might be related, when we navigate to the Cortana dashboard page (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/dashboard#!/home) we get the following error:

> We are unable to load your skills at this time. Please refresh the page or try again later.

Does anyone know how these errors can be troubleshooted?